# How to prove that if $S(n)$ is triangular number for $n \in Z_{+}$, then $a=9 $?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a\ge 1$ is natural number.
Denote $S(n)=1+a+a^2+a^3+...+a^n$ for $n=1,2,3,...$
How to prove that: if $S(n)$ is triangular number for $n \in Z_{+}$, then $a=9 $?

 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularNumber.html

Comment: I think you mean $a>1$ since $a=1$ would make $S(n)=n+1$, so then $S(n)$ could be any triangular number

Comment: @vrugtehagel Actually all numbers of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n 9^k$, for $n \ge 1$, seem to be triangular (I checked it up to $n=20$). The OP asks for a proof of the uniqueness of $9$ having such property.

Comment: Ah, that was unclear to me. It makes sense now.

Comment: @Crostul:  Here is the proof for that direction:  A number $k$ is triangular if and only if $1+8k$ is a square.  You can prove that by writing $k=p(p+1)/2$ and using the quadratic formula for $p$.   We have $S(n)=\frac {a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$, so if $a=9, 8S(n)+1=9^{n+1}=(3^{n+1})^2$, so $S(n)$ is triangular.  I think the other direction is harder, as I find sporadic cases up to $S(4)$, so it seems unlikely you can just prove a particular $S(n)$ is never triangular unless $a=9$

Comment: @RossMillikan I just checked on my own that $$\sum_{k \le n}9^k = \binom{(3^{n+1}+1)/2}{2}$$

Comment: Perhaps relevant: $S(2)$ is triangular if and only if $a$ is in the sequence at https://oeis.org/A216134 $(1, 4, 9, 26, 55, \ldots)$.  I also find the sporadic solutions $a = 2, 23$ for $n = 3$ and no others for $n \le 5, a \le 10^7$.

Comment: If we can prove that all $n$ such that $2(n^2+n-1)^2+7$ is a perfect square are $1$ and $4$, then we're done. I've checked this up to $n<10000$ so it's probably true.